# MySQL Finding expired paid records

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables of data members which contains member names with an auto ID called member_id and a paid table which stores an expiration date and the member_id as well for joining between the two tables.

I'm trying to do a query which will return all members who have not renewed this year by selecting paid records from 2017 with a NOT EXIST clause. This query returns no results though.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM members
     , paid
 WHERE members.member_id = paid.member_id
   AND paid.year = '2016-12-31'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT members.member_id 
                      FROM members
                         , paid
                     WHERE members.member_id = paid.member_id
                       AND paid.year = '2017-12-31')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I suspect that familiarization with JOINs would pay dividends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM members
   JOIN paid
   ON members.member_id = paid.member_id
   WHERE paid.year = '2016-12-31'
   AND members.member_id NOT IN ( SELECT members.member_id 
                      FROM members
                      JOIN paid
                      ON members.member_id = paid.member_id
                      WHERE paid.year = '2017-12-31')
```

Comment: I get the same result with this. Nothing returned in the query.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about 'paid.year'

Comment: It's a time date stamp. So each member name is in the members table joined to it's member_id in the paid table. Each year a member who pays gets a new date stamp record. We want to find who hasn't renewed from last year which means the paid table has a 2016-12-31 expiration and not members who already have a 2017-12-31 who have paid for the new year.

Comment: so If a member paid on 2017-12-28, his paid.year will be '2017-12-31' or something else?

Comment: Yes, we use the end of year for all our expiration paid records. So to make this easy we have member John Andersen and Mark Smith in the members tables. John Andersen is member_id 1 and Mark Smith is member_id 2. Both of these are in the paid table for example. member_id 1 year = 2016-12-31 and also member_id 1 year = 2017-12-31. But Mark Smith member_id 2 has only a paid year of 2016-12-31 so we want to find him. We are basically looking for a query of members who have not renewed.

Comment: Check the updated query, it uses NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS

Comment: That appears to work correctly. Why does NOT IN work?

Comment: NOT EXISTS (subquery) means the subquery should not return any rows.
While,
parameter NOT IN (subquery)  means parameter should NOT be IN rows returned by subquery.